# Is there a Coffeescript equivalent for Dart

Tags: coffeescript, dart

The main aspect of CoffeeScript I'd like to see available also for Dart in form of a different, Dart-based language would be less verbosity, less brackets, less Java-style.

Does such solution exist ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

If you don't want to have your field static you can omit the `static` keyword.
If you don't want to have your field final you can write `var` or a concrete type instead of the `final` keyword.

And if you don't want a loop you can omit `for`, `while`, `forEach`, ...

Comment: Sorry if you got me wrong. edited the question. `static final` was only an example for a little bit of verbosity from Dart's side. (I was missing `static` in JS btw). For many, including myself, CS, Python, etc. - languages without braces are more readable, hence the question.

Comment: There are always advantages and drawbacks. The Dart language designers decided to go with the C style because many developers are used to it and it's considered less error prone than languages like Python which depend on indentation. And this is my opinion too. I like the braces, they make the code more readable. You see this is highly opinionated and probably the reason why you got downvotes because such mostly opinionated questions are off topic on SO.

Comment: I must disagree with perceiving this question as opinionated :)
I'm not asking for an upheaval in the core language. I would only be very pleased to get **some another** Dart-based language which is brackets-fee and use it for my projects.

Comment: And to this part of your question my answer was 'No'. Dart is as it is, there are no derivates (yet).